# <?php echo $_SERVER[“PHP_SELF”];?> qual a função?

Tags: php

Estava estudando sobre métodos POST e tudo bem, sei que o formulário precisa de processar e por isso é encaminhado via action, mas qual a função do código:

```
action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>
```

esse $_SERVER[“PHP_SELF”] reflete a própria página no servidor para realizar o “processamento” é isso?

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Example of PHP POST method</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
if(isset($_POST["name"])){
    echo "<p>Hi, " . $_POST["name"] . "</p>";
}
?>
**<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>"**
    <label for="inputName">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="inputName">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sim, `$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]` é o caminho para o próprio arquivo em questão. Desta forma, ao submeter o formulário, a requisição POST será enviada para ele mesmo. Porém, não é recomendado que faça isso.

Se seu arquivo possui o nome `cadastro.php`, ao acessar, por exemplo, `/cadastro.php`, o formulário no HTML ficará:

```
<form method="post" action="cadastro.php">
```

Parece tudo certo, mas isso abre algumas brechas na sua aplicação. Alguém provido de más intenções poderia muito bem acessar a URL

```
/cadastro.php/%22%3E%3Cscript%3Ealert('xss')%3C/script%3E
```

Dependendo de como está configurado seu servidor e, principalmente, se não tratou devidamente todas as entradas do usuário, seu HTML ficaria:

```
<form method="post" action="cadastro.php">
<script>alert('xss')</script>
```

Isto é, você permitiria que o usuário adicione um *script* JS na sua página, o que caracteriza um ataque XSS, caso queira ler mais.

Outro ponto é que, idealmente, a resposta a uma requisição POST deveria conter o cabeçalho `Location` para redirecionar o usuário. Da maneira que fez, o usuário irá ver a mesma tela, com o formulário, com a mensagem "Hi Fulano". Se o usuário atualizar esta página, o navegador irá perguntar se deseja reenviar as informações. Neste caso não haverá nenhum efeito colateral, mas imagina que isso é um formulário de contato; cada vez que o usuário atualizasse a página um e-mail diferente seria enviado.

Por isso, idealmente, a resposta da requisição POST possui o cabeçalho `Location` para uma URL que representa o recurso criado. No redirecionamento, o navegador irá efetuar uma requisição GET na URL indicada, removendo o problema de reenvio das informações do formulário, podendo o usuário atualizar a página livremente.

Claro, cada caso é um caso.